# How to make newline writing in my case? TS

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have that piece of code:

```
let list: Array<string> =[]; 
    
    page.on('request', request =>      list.push('>>', request.method(), request.url()+'\\n'));  
    page.on('response', response =>       list.push('<<',String( response.status()), response.url()+'\\n'));
```

I'm trying to divide that pushes into separated lines, but unsuccessfully.
My goal is to write these strings in new lines and save it to JSON in that view. Or just to rebuild the JSON to get that view.

What do I have now:
[image]

What am I trying to get:

[image]

Could you help me please with that?

Answer (score 1):

Generally use **\n** for line break.
**\\n** not work.

Not know if is you case.

Comment: \n doesn't work as well

Answer (score 0):

Try using [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#multi-line_strings) with the backtic character (`` ` ``) instead of single quotes (`'`)

Comment: sorry but didn't help